# Iterating through rows of selected column in dataframe to "clean" each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to prepare data for statistical analysis and have encountered a problem with white spaces within the dataset. Where is the mistake in my function?

This is the code I've created, using functions that usually solve the problem. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case for dataframes. Some background info regarding the dataframe: the column I want to clean is "LOCATION", which contains strings describing an address.

```
for i in data.index:
    data.at[i, "LOCATION"] = data.at[i, "LOCATION"].split()
    data.at[i, "LOCATION"] = " ".join(data.at[i, "LOCATION"])
```

Example row (uncleaned) '15300________SATICOY____________ST' 
 *the _ represent spaces

Said row after using split() ['15300', 'SATICOY', 'ST']

After joining '1 5 3 0 0                   S A T I C O Y                                             S T'

The code works fine until I actually want to join the strings back together. My goal is to join the strings divided by a space, so "15300 SATICOY ST".

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Please be a bit clearer. What is your intended result? To me it sounds like nothing will be changed after your cleaning (split by blank space, then join it again with blank space)

Comment: Are you trying to remove 'excess' whitespace...? maybe `data['LOCATION'] = data['LOCATION'].str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip()` ?

Comment: Hi, I hadn't seen that several spaces are displayed as one. I hope it is clearer now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop here, use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex` expression `\s+` *(1 or more whitespace characters)*. Replace this with 1 space:

```
data['LOCATION'] = data['LOCATION'].str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

Comment: @fjv94 no problem buddy. Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Its easy -
Do this

```
data["LOCATION"]=data["LOCATION"].str.strip(" ") # this will remove all the trailing and leading spaces
data["LOCATION"]=data["LOCATION"].str.replace('\s+', ' ') #this will remove all the extra spaces.
```